# Как установить PIL/pillow в Python 3.4.3?

Tags: python, pip, pillow

При установке через `pip install` в командной строке появляется ошибка. В папке Scripts pip и EI установлены, и эта папка добавлена в PATH. Работаю через Python IDLE
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: pip — это программа, которую нужно запускать в командной строке системы, а не в командной строке питона

Comment: "pip не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом"

Comment: Значит вы забыли перейти в папку с этими программами или забыли добавить папку с программами в переменную окружения PATH

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить ту же самую команду, но только в командной строке, например вот так: `pip install Pillow==2.2.1`.

Или же если Вы работаете в jupyter notebook, то добавьте в начале  команды `!` и просто вставьте в запускаемую строчку, вот так:

```
    In [1]: !pip install Pillow==2.2.1
```

Кстати если сомневаетесь правильно ли написали команду для установки по протоколу `pip`, то её всегда можно проверить на сайте [*PyPi*](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.1/) как я это сделал сейчас.